# Call same CABasicAnimation multiple times

Tags: ios, swift, animation, core-animation, cabasicanimation

I currently have a hack which works, but is not ideal. I want to call the same animation multiple times before the first time I call it ends. I'm using a `delay` function because I don't understand how to implement what I want correctly with Core Animation. Any ideas on how to remove the `delay` function calls here and use Core Animation methods/properties instead to get the same results?

This is my animation:

```
func animateCircle() {
    // The circle in its smallest size.
    let circlePath1 = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: self.center, radius: CGFloat(3), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)

    // The circle in its largest size.
    let circlePath2 = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: self.center, radius: CGFloat(60), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)

    // Configure the layer.
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let green = UIColor(red: 0, green: 222, blue: 183, alpha: 100)
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = green.CGColor
    shapeLayer.fillColor = green.CGColor
    // This is the path that's visible when there'd be no animation.
    shapeLayer.path = circlePath1.CGPath
    self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

    // Animate the path.
    let pathAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
    pathAnimation.fromValue = circlePath1.CGPath
    pathAnimation.toValue = circlePath2.CGPath

    // Animate the alpha value.
    let alphaAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    alphaAnimation.fromValue = 1
    alphaAnimation.toValue = 0

    // We want both animations to run together perfectly, so we
    // put them into an animation group.
    let group = CAAnimationGroup()
    group.animations = [pathAnimation, alphaAnimation]
    group.duration = 2.4
    group.repeatCount = FLT_MAX

    // Add the animation to the layer.
    shapeLayer.addAnimation(group, forKey:"sonar")
}
```

This is how I call the function:

```
  func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    animateCircle()

    delay(0.8) {
        self.animateCircle()
    }

    delay(1.6) {
        self.animateCircle()
    }
}
```

Note the two uses of `delay`. I would not like to use these. Any thoughts?

Comment: you can try CAKeyframeAnimation

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks for replying! I just started using Core Animation andI think I've seen that before. Could you provide an answer to this or a good article?

Comment: objc.io has a [nice article on animations](https://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/animations-explained/) - including `CAKeyframeAnimation`.